# Is there a name for this kind of design?

Tags: style-identification

[image]

Some more examples, taken from the Jira website:

[image]

I'm seeing this design alot lately, and I was wondering if there's a name for it.

Comment: I know a lot of designers that call pages they make in this style "infographic pages". I sometimes refer to it as icon-based web design. Not totally sure if either of those are official names though.

Comment: It's a drawing using geometric shapes and line art. Could be called icons. Could be called flat. Could be called all sorts of stuff.

Comment: I have added some more examples.

Answer (score 2):

It's a combination of monoweight (single stroke weight) and flat design.

Answer (score 0):

## Thin Line Flat Design

Into Flat Design, Google Search gives many information as [Thin Line Flat Design](https://www.google.es/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1486&bih=1136&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=GZHKXKjAFaWRlwTaxJ5A&q=thin%20line%20flat%20design&oq=thin%20line%20flat%20design&gs_l=img.3...10375.11756..12093...0.0..0.76.576.9......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30.RKNfA9wPgzQ#imgrc=_)

---

*Thin line flat design icons* by Darko Vujic at [Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/29530971/Thin-line-flat-design-icons)

[image]

---

*Thin line flat design concept banners* by Graphics4u at [Graphicriver](https://graphicriver.net/item/thin-line-flat-design-concept-banners/13135483)

[image]

Answer (score -3):

This illustration style is pretty popular in Material Design. You can find some examples of the style by searching "Material Design Illustration".

Here are a few examples that come up in that search:

[image: Material Design Illustration Example 01]

[image: Material Design Illustration Example 02]

[image: Material Design Illustration Example 03]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design Stack Exchange! Before deciding what's "legit" ("on topic", in the local Stack Exchange lingo), you may want to read the introductory [tour] and [What topics can I ask here?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As was commented, there are some further guidelines for identification of styles and fonts.

Comment: Hmm documentation says "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." Looks like it can be a little harder than one would think to get a simple question answered.

Comment: Or I should say the tour says

Comment: I'm not really sure that this is material design, and if it is, it is pretty broad. Please see my other examples I've just added.

Comment: I typed in "google material design illustration" goo.gl/kNXAoi

Comment: I was looking, trying to find what the name of this technique was called myself and everything I read pointed to Material Design because how 2 dimensional it is and how popular it has become.